Projective curve covered by two affine pieces

A non-singular projective curve $X$ is covered by two affine pieces (with respect to different embeddings) which are affine plane curves with equations $y^2 = f (x)$ and $v^2 = g(u)$ respectively, with f a square-free polynomial of even degree 2n and $u = 1/x, v = y/x^n$ in $K(X)$. Determine the polynomial g(u) and show that
the canonical class on X has degree $2n − 4$. Why can we not just say that $X$ is the projective plane curve associated to the affine curve $y^2 = f (x)$?

First course in algebraic geometry, $k$ is closed. I'd appreciate if someone could check my solution here, I found this question conceptually very difficult. I don't really know how to picture whats going on. I think $y^2=f(x)$ is supposed to describe the 'finite' points of the curve and $v^2=g(u)$ describes the behaviour at infinity, and this distinguishes it from usual homogenization. It turns out (below), this only corresponds to two points at infinity, $(u,v)=(0,\pm 1)$. Yet the result implies the curve is genus $n-1$, which is very non-intuitive.
$g(u)=u^{2n}f(1/u)$ -- algebra omitted.
I take $\omega = dx$. $x-x_0$ is a local parameter at points $(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0\neq 0$ and by construction this has no zeros or poles. When $y_0=0$, $y$ is a local parameter and we write
$$\omega = \frac{2y}{f'}dy$$.
We know that $f'$ is a unit at these points so we can ignore it. There are $2n$ distinct points of the form $(x_0,0)$, so we have counted $2n$ zeros of $\omega$ so far.
Now, we need to look at infinity. If $u\neq 0$, then the map between embeddings tells us we have already looked at that part, so the remaining points to look at are when $u=0$. At these points, $v^2=g(0)=1$ so we need to look at $(0,\pm 1)$ and $u$ is a local parameter here (just as $x-x_0$ was), so writing
$$\omega = \frac{-1}{u^2} du$$
we see there is a pole order 2 at each of these points.

Yes, your work is correct. You can compare with my answer here, which contains basically the same calculations as yours.
Regarding the unusual definition of the curve: if one takes the affine plane curve $y^2 = f(x)$ and just tries homogenizing it, the resulting projective plane curve given by $Y^2 Z^{2n-2} = Z^{2n} f(X/Z)$ will have a singular point at infinity. To get a nonsingular model, one typically considers the closure in weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,n,1)$, where instead of the usual action of $k^\times$ defining projective space, we take the weighted action
$$
\lambda \cdot (U, V, W) = (\lambda U, \lambda^n V, \lambda W) \, .
$$
The transition functions between the open set where $W \neq 0$ and the open set where $U \neq 0$ are then given by the formulas you wrote above. (I compute these transitions functions when $n=2$ in my answer here.)
So the upshot is that this curve is not the projective plane curve obtained by taking the closure in $\mathbb{P}^2$, as this would have a singular point. It is instead the closure in $\mathbb{P}(1,n,1)$.
Let $g$ be the genus of the curve. Here's an alternative way to see that we must have $g = n-1$. Consider the projection map $\pi: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto x$ on the first affine patch, or
\begin{align*}
\pi: X &\to \mathbb{P}^1\\
[U : V : W] &\mapsto [U : W]
\end{align*}
in weighted projective space. Generically, the fiber of $\pi$ above a point $x_0$ consists of the $2$ points $\{(x_0, \sqrt{f(x_0)}), (x_0, -\sqrt{f(x_0)})\}$, so $\deg(\pi) = 2$. The points $x_0$ above which $\pi$ is ramified are those such that the fiber has size $1$, which occurs exactly when $f(x_0) = 0$, i.e., $x_0$ is one of the $2n$ roots of $f$. (You showed that there are $2$ points at infinity, so $\pi$ is unramified above $\infty = [1:0] \in \mathbb{P}^1$.) At these points the ramification index is $2$, so applying the Riemann--Hurwitz formula, we have
\begin{align*}
2g - 2 = 2(2 \cdot 0 - 2) + \sum_{i=1}^{2n} (2-1) = 2n-4 \, .
\end{align*}
Thus $g = n-1$, as you found by computing the degreeof the canonical class.
